# IF no funciona correctamente en AJAX // JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Buenas amigos, tengo un problema, el if no me funciona correctamente, tengo un input type number el cual le debo ingresar una cantidad mayor a 0 y menor al maximo establecido, pero si cumplo esas condiciones correctamente igual me tira la condicional como no valida y se dirige al else, cualquier ayuda les agradezco.[introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B2Qtm.png)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
    //VERIFICACION DE VALORES PARA BOTON DE SEND COSECHA
$(document).on('keyup', '.cantCosecha', function () {
  let cant = $(this).val(); //VALOR DEL INGRESO
  let max = $(this).attr('max'); //ATRIBUTO AGREGADO AUTO QUE ES 1000 EN ESTE CASO
  console.log(cant);  //CANTIDAD QUE INGRESO
  console.log(max);  //ESTA CANTIDAD ES 1000
  if (cant <= max && cant > 0 && cant.length > 0) { //CONDICION POSITIVA LA CUAL ME PERMITE SEGUIR CON LA COSECHA
    $('.stopCosecha').css("display","none")
    $('.sendCosecha').css("display","flex")
    $(".sendCosecha").css("background-color", "green");
  } else {     // CONDICION NEGATIVA
    $('.stopCosecha').css("display","flex")
    $('.sendCosecha').css("display","none")
    $(".sendCosecha").css("background-color", "red");
  }
});
```

// HTML

```
              <input type="number" value="" class="boton-cultivo cantCosecha" min="1" max="${cantidad}" Placeholder="Cantidad de la Cosecha">
          <i class="fas fa-check boton-cultivo sendCosecha" id="sendCosecha" cantidad="${cantidad}" vegetal="${idVegetal}" variedad="${idVariedad}"></i>
          <i class="fas fa-times boton-cultivo stopCosecha"></i>
```

Comment: Creo que tú error está en tus condicionales (if (cant <= max && cant > 0 && cant.length > 0)) si cant es un entero, no puedes hacerle in .length a menos que lo conviertas a string, te va a retornar un undefined y por eso nunca entra a tu caso. puedes agregar un console.log() para validar si en efecto entra al if, pero no lo creo.

Comment: si, ya he probado sin la condicion cant.length y tampoco entra, esa la agregue para que el input tenga datos si o si. Pero no, tampoco funciona sin esa condicion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Los atributos se leen como string, por consiguiente estas comparando (mayor y menor) contra string's, no tengo idea de la lógica de javascript para estos casos, pero supongo que tiene que ver con la conversión a ASCII, parecido a lo que pasan en la ordenación alfanumérica

```js
console.log("10000"<"2") //true
console.log("1"<"2") //true
console.log("4"<"2") //false
```

Debes convertir tus atributos a Number

```
let cant = Number( $(this).val() ); //VALOR DEL INGRESO
let max  = Number( $(this).attr('max') );
```

Además quitar el cant.length que no tiene sentido ahora que es Number

Comment: me funciono perfecto amigo, era eso, gracias por la respuesta!